# Android asynchronous programming without opening a new process?

Tags: android, asynchronous, httprequest

Is it possible to do something asynchronous, such as perform an HTTP request, without forking the thread? In windows or Linux I don't usually see any application making a child process for each HTTP request, so I would like to do the same with Android. Otherwise to me it seems like it's overkill and adds an unnecessarily high priority to my application.

If anyone is familiar with JavaScript, I'd like to do asynchronous stuff just like it. Having a sort of queue of what to do, and everything is actually in one thread, even though they are asynchronous. It uses some sort of queuing mechanism.

Of course I may know this incorrectly, and using Threads or AsyncTask maybe doesn't actually open a new process.

Comment: Your title says process, but your question seems to be mostly about threads.  Granted on linux (including android) threads are implemented using lightweight processes, but the lightweight is significant - you share address space.  A thread that is blocked waiting for work or results should not cost much to have around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instances run using a shared pool of threads that already exist (unless you specify your own executor, of course), avoiding the overhead of spawning new threads all the time.  Use those.

Comment: So is does this result to the same kind of asynchronous programming behavior that is used typically in Windows, Linux and OS X applications? A typical application for such an OS that downloads images by HTTP asynchronously and displays them also use separate threads, which are run in an OS-defined shared process?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the models used in those other operating systems, so I can't comment usefully about that.  The intent for `AsyncTask` is for short things that you don't want to have block the UI thread.  If you are doing heavier stuff, you should start looking into using a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead.